# Create a window that displays just the date, just like xarclock, except for the date

Tags: window, date, xterm

I want to create a window that simply displays the date, with as many of these requirements as possible

```
- a -geom option

- a -bg and -fg option to specify background and foreground options

- an option to set the font.

- the usual formatting options that come with the `date` command.
```

The perfect solution for me would be the exact analog of `xarclock`, see below, but capable of displaying a custom formatted date instead of the time.

[image]

I could of course do this inside an `xterm` but as far as I can tell, there's no simple way of opening an `xterm` without a title bar.     Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Comment: Read `man xclock xarclock xterm`

Comment: ???? @waltinator, you must have seen something I haven't.   Of course I've read all these man page. Based on the man pages,  `xclock` doesn't have a geometry option, `xarclock` doesn't report the date, and `xterm` doesn't offer the option to suppress the title bar.       Please tell me what I missed...